# Reading file and save information in a liked list using fgets and strtok in C

Tags: c, linked-list, fgets, strtok

I'm trying to read a file which has only one line with names separated by commas, so i'm using fgets to read the line and then separate the names with strtok, then i wanted to save those names in a linked list. I'm using CodeBlocks and when i run the program it shows this message: "Process terminated with status -1073741510"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define MAX_CHAR 200

typedef struct Names{
    char* name;
    struct Names* next;
}Names;

Names* create_list(){

    Names* aux = (Names*) malloc (sizeof(Names));
    assert(aux);
    aux->next = NULL;
    return aux;
}
void insert_name (Names* n, char* p){

    Names* aux = (Names*)malloc(sizeof(Names));
    aux->name = p;
    while(n->next!=NULL){
        n=n->next;
    }
    aux->next=n->next;
    n->next=aux;
}

void config(Names*p){

    FILE* fp = fopen( "names.txt", "r");

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file");
        return;
    }
    else{
        char line[MAX_CHAR],*token;

        fgets(line, MAX_CHAR, fp);
        token = strtok(line,",");
        insert_name(p,token);
        while(token != NULL);{
            token = strtok(NULL,",");
            insert_name(p,token);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

void print_list(Names* n){
    Names* l = n->next;
    while (l){
        printf("%s\n",l->name);
        l = l -> next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Names* n;
    n = create_list();
    config(n);
    print_list(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Surely you mean `struct Names* next` in your struct?

Comment: Hahah yes, sure, i forgot to change that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an infinite loop here:

```
while(token != NULL);{
```

The semicolon terminates the "body" of the `while` and the curly brace just opens a code block that isn't attached to any control structure. (That's legal and was a way to scope variables before C99.)

Without the semicolon, the loop is still wrong: You should only insert when you know that the token isn't `NULL`:

```
token = strtok(line,",");

while (token != NULL) {
    insert_name(p,token);
    token = strtok(NULL,",");
}
```

There are still errors in your code:

- Your tokens are pointers into the local array ´line`. When you leave`config`, these pointers become invalid, because`line` will become invalid. You should copy the strings instead just storing a pointer.
- At the end of the program, you should call `free` for every call to `malloc`. In other eords, clean up your list.

Comment: Thank you so much! The thing is, now the program runs but when i close the execution window it still shows "Process terminated with status -1073741510". Shouldn't i correct this?

Comment: You said that i should copy the string but to where? I have to create another variable in the function config? I'm sorry i'm new to this stuff!

Comment: Good question. There are several possibilities: Make `name` an array and copy the token there. Drawback: The array has a fixed size, which means you waste space for short strings and you have to cut long strings short. SG92 has shown another possibility: Allocate memory and copy the name there. Drawback: You have to free the memory later. Prefer option 2, but make sure you `malloc(strlen(s) + 1)` so that the null-terminator at the end will fit, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think firstly you need modify assignment of name to strcpy or memcpy and also use dynamic allocation

```
  aux->name = (char*) malloc(strlen(p));
  strcpy(aux->name, p);
```

or

```
  typedef struct Names{
     char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
     struct Names* next;
  }Names;
  //and use strcpy or memcpy in insert_name function
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Good advice, but you should allocate one byte more for the null terminator.